# Woo-Commerce Send mail by code.

Tags: email, woocommerce-offtopic

I am doing custom order is working fine but mail is not working so i am trying to use the default woo-commerce mailing functionality. i found the class from where woo-commerce send mail but when i am using the class it give me error.

Class and Function which i am calling

`WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order::trigger( $order_id );`

It give me bellow error.

Class 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order' not found in function.php.

I am call function in functions.php

Comment: Why i got negative vote on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research on google and woocommerce code i found the ans of the what i what.

i have use following function for to send the mail to the user once order have been generated using the custom code in wordpress woo-commerce.

`WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger($orderId);`